# Ｗhat is the difference between くつろぐ and のんびり?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

These words were used in a chat, according to jisho.org both terms mean being relaxed or taking it easy. How do you use them?

Comment: Have you considered using HiNative.com you would get a lot more attention.

Comment: ＠道理百遍義理一遍、This site is more helpful to me.

Comment: @道理百遍義理一遍, I am appreciative of your assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They belong to different word classes. のんびり is an adverb and suru-verb, and くつろぐ is a verb on its own. That means のんびり (without する) and くつろぐ are never interchangeable.

[image]

The difference between のんびり**する** and くつろぐ is small and they are mostly interchangeable. But くつろぐ tends to refer to relaxing physically (e.g., in a sofa, doing almost nothing). のんびりする tends to refer to mentally feeling relaxed, not being pressed for time. You can say のんびりする even when mild physical activities are involved (e.g., ハワイでダイビングやドライブをしながらのんびり過ごした).